# Gmail API NodeJS code sample doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I was using the Gmail API Node Quickstart tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

But it doesn't seem to work. Specifically, the json file I got for registering my application is not in the structure this code sample expects.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "...",
  "client_email": "...",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "...",
  "token_uri": "...",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "...",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
}
```

The code is looking for a client_secret, client_id, and redirect_uris. client_id is obviously the same that's still in the json file, but I don't know about the other two?

Answer (score 0):

You've created/downloaded a credential for a service account. Kindly double check the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) and follow the *Step 1* carefully. Before creating a credential, verify if you have selected/placed the correct information required in the quickstart.

[image]

Hope this helps.